How to Trace Source Data in an OpenAI-based Chatbot Using Langchain and Third-Party Custom Tools like Tavily API
I'm developing a chatbot leveraging OpenAI's model with Langchain and integrating third-party tools like Tavily Search. I've structured my chatbot to use a main OpenAI chat model agent that can utilize custom APIs. Each of these APIs is effectively a Langchain agent with access to one or multiple tools, such as web search APIs that interface with Tavily.

I'm looking for a way to trace back or log the sources of data that the agent pulls from when generating responses. The goal is to understand which source (url , text , metadata ...) contributed to the bot's response. Below is an overview of my code structure, focusing on how I've set up routes, services, and tool initialization.
Essentially, my question is, how can I integrate source traceability within my chatbot's workflow to track and reveal the origins (URLs, texts, metadata) of the data it uses, particularly ensuring tools like Tavily Search to provide both response content and its original data sources?
Has anyone had experience implementing such traceability in a Langchain and OpenAI-based setup? Any suggestions or references to documentation that might help in enriching my chatbot's response with sources would be greatly appreciate.
Thank you for your time, and I eagerly await the collective wisdom that this community never fails to provide!

So far, I've implemented the main logic for my chatbot, including integrating OpenAI's Langchain and Tavily Search functionalities. My methods handle initializing tools, crafting prompts, and executing agents to generate chat completions. However, I have not been able to devise a system that consistently captures and logs the data sources that the chatbot uses to formulate its responses.
My expectation is that, by modifying the bot’s search tools and execution logic, I could make the chatbot’s operations transparent by having it log the origins of information used in each response, similar to how a browser history records visited web pages. This would include capturing URLs, snippets of texts, or metadata from Tavily Search results that the chatbot uses when conversing with the user.
Below is a detailed explanation of the code :
createNewCompletion:
This method is part of a service class that performs the business logic of creating a new completion.

It initializes a set of tools the chat model can use with this.initializeTools(userId, parameters.toolsList).
Sets up the default OpenAI chat model with this.initializeChatModel(userId, parameters).
Parses the chat history for a given userId and chatId with this.chatHistoryParser(userId, chatId).
Executes an agent with this.openAiToolsAgentExecutor that will generate the completion based on all the provided data.
Returns a success message with the generated completion data.

  async createNewCompletion(
    userId: number,
    chatId: number,
    dto: CreateNewCompletionDto,
  ) {
      //....
      const parameters = await this.getChatModelParameters(userId, chatId);

      const tools = this.initializeTools(userId, parameters.toolsList);

      delete parameters.toolsList;
      const chatModel = await this.initializeChatModel(userId, parameters);

      const messages = await this.chatHistoryParser(userId, chatId);

      const completion = await this.openAiToolsAgentExecutor(
        chatModel,
        tools,
        messages,
        dto,
        userId,
        chatId,
      );

      return {
        message: 'Completion created successfully',
        data: completion,
      };
      //....
  }

OpenAI Tools Agent Executor - openAiToolsAgentExecutor Method:
This method executes the OpenAI tools agent to generate a chat completion.

A prompt is created with ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages, instructing the agent on how it should behave as a helpful assistant.
An instance of an OpenAI tools agent is created with specific tools and the prepared prompt.
The agent is executed with provided messages and the DTO prompt from the user, by creating a new AgentExecutor and invoking it.
The completion result from the executor is then returned.

  private async openAiToolsAgentExecutor(
    llm,
    tools,
    messages,
    dto,
    userId,
    chatId,
  ) {
      //...
      const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
        [
          'system',
          'You are a helpful assistant. Answer all questions to the best of your ability. Use the suite of tools provided if needed. You may not need to use tools for every query - the user may just want to chat!',
        ],
        new MessagesPlaceholder('messages'),
        new MessagesPlaceholder('agent_scratchpad'),
      ]);

      const agent = await createOpenAIToolsAgent({
        llm,
        tools,
        prompt,
      });

      const executor = new AgentExecutor({
        agent,
        tools,
      });

      const completion = await executor.invoke({
        messages: [...messages, new HumanMessage(dto.prompt)],
      });

      //....
    
      return completion ;
     
      //...
  }

Initialization of Tools - initializeTools Method:
A private method in a service class initializes a set of tools that the OpenAI model can use during the execution.

It creates an instance of DynamicStructuredTool to perform web searches.
The function within the DynamicStructuredTool performs a search using this.toolServices.tavilySearch, passing the user's query and handling the successes or possible errors.

 private initializeTools(userId: number, toolsList: string[]) {
    const tools = [
      //....
      new DynamicStructuredTool({
        name: 'WEB_SEARCH_API',
        description: 'Call this to search the web',
        schema: z.object({
          query: z.string().describe('Query to search the web'),
        }),
        func: async ({ query }) => {
          try {
            const { data } = await this.toolServices.tavilySearch(userId, {
              query: `We need to search the web for the following query: ${query}`,
            });

            return data.output;
          } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Error searching the web');
          }
        },
      }),
      //....
    ];

    // Filter the allTools array to only include tools whose name is in the toolsList array
    const selectedTools =
      toolsList.length > 0
        ? tools.filter((tool) => toolsList.includes(tool.name))
        : tools;

    return selectedTools;
  }

Tavily Search API - tavilySearch Method:
A method that makes use of the TavilySearchDto to perform a web search using Tavily tools.

It sets up the tools needed for the Tavily search using this.searchWithTavilyTools(TOOL_KEY).
It then executes the search with these tools and returns the search results wrapped in a success message.


  async tavilySearch(userId: number, dto: TavilySearchDto) {
      //....
      const TOOL_KEY = 'TAVILY_SEARCH';

      const chatModel = await this.initializeChatModel(userId);

      const tools = this.searchWithTavilyTools(TOOL_KEY);

      const executor = this.tavilyAgentExecutor(chatModel, tools);

      const completion = await executor.invoke({
        input: dto.query,
      });

      return {
        message: 'Tavily search completed successfully.',
        data: completion,
      };
      //....

  }


Search With Tavily Tools - searchWithTavilyTools Method:
A private method to initialize the Tavily search tool.

It creates an instance of DynamicStructuredTool configured for the Tavily search.
The function of this tool performs a web search via an internal mechanism and returns the result.

  private searchWithTavilyTools(toolName: string) {
      //...
      const tavily = this.initializeTavilySearchTool();

      const tavilySearchTool = new DynamicStructuredTool({
        name: toolName,
        description:
          'Call this to search on the web and get the most relevant information based on the query.',
        schema: z.object({
          query: z.string().describe('The query to search on the web.'),
        }),
        func: async ({ query }) => {
          try {
            const result = await tavily.invoke(query);

            return result;
          } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Error while searching the web with Tavily.');
          }
        },
      });

      const tools = [tavilySearchTool];

      return tools;
      //....
  }

Tavily Agent Executor - tavilyAgentExecutor Method:
A private method setting up an agent executor for Tavily search.

The method creates a prompt for the Tavily search agent.
The chatModel is enhanced with a set of functions corresponding to the tools provided.
An AgentExecutor is created with this configured model and the tools, ready to execute queries given to it.

 private tavilyAgentExecutor(
    chatModel: ChatOpenAI<ChatOpenAICallOptions>,
    tools: DynamicStructuredTool<
      z.ZodObject<
        {
          query: z.ZodString;
        },
        'strip',
        z.ZodTypeAny,
        {
          query?: string;
        },
        {
          query?: string;
        }
      >
    >[],
  ) {
      //.....
      const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
        [
          'system',
          'You are an exceptionally adept assistant with advanced capabilities in web search. Your task is to meticulously search the web for the most relevant information based on the user query. Utilize the comprehensive suite of tools at your disposal to expertly retrieve the required information, ensuring accuracy and relevance in every aspect of your search.',
        ],
        ['human', '{input}'],
        new MessagesPlaceholder('agent_scratchpad'),
      ]);
      const modelWithFunctions = chatModel.bind({
        functions: tools.map((tool) => convertToOpenAIFunction(tool)),
      });
      const runnableAgent = RunnableSequence.from([
        {
          input: (i: { input: string; steps: AgentStep[] }) => i.input,
          agent_scratchpad: (i: { input: string; steps: AgentStep[] }) =>
            formatToOpenAIFunctionMessages(i.steps),
        },
        prompt,
        modelWithFunctions,
        new OpenAIFunctionsAgentOutputParser(),
      ]);

      const executor = AgentExecutor.fromAgentAndTools({
        agent: runnableAgent,
        tools,
      });

      return executor;
      //....
  }


You can use langfuse

Traces, evals, prompt management and metrics to debug and improve your
LLM application.

you create langfuse client
import os
from langfuse.client import Langfuse
langfuse=Langfuse(
    os.environ("LANGFUSE_PUBLIC_KEY"),
    os.environ("LANGFUSE_SECRET_KEY"),
    
)

then integrate it to your chain with
from langfuse.model import CreateTrace
create trace object which has all the callback functions tied to it
trace=langfuse.trace(
    CreateTrace(
        id=chat_args.conversation_id,
        metadata=chat_args.metadata
    )
)

on your chain implementaion add callbacks
 callbacks=[trace.getNewHandler()]

more on tracing
